# Making changes to firebase project locally

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm, localhost, firebase-tools

I am working on a firebase project and trying to make local changes and test them. However, after I make the changes and run "npm run echo" and "firebase emulators:start", the changes do not reflect on my local host connection. I am very new to firebase, is there something I am missing out?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.